# Load log data in hive table using serde regex is null

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, hive-serde

**I want to parse this log sample**

> May  3 11:52:54 cdh-dn03 init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (1208)
>   killed by TERM signal
>
> May  3 11:53:31 cdh-dn03 kernel: registered taskstats version 1
>
> May  3 11:53:31 cdh-dn03 kernel: sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 32x/32x
>   xa/form2 tray
>
> May  3 11:53:31 cdh-dn03 kernel: piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base
>   address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
>
> May  3 11:53:31 cdh-dn03 kernel: nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (7972
>   buckets, 31888 max)
>
> May  3 11:53:57 cdh-dn03 kernel: hrtimer: interrupt took 11250457 ns
>
> May  3 11:53:59 cdh-dn03 ntpd_initres[1705]: host name not found:
>   0.rhel.pool.ntp.org

**This is how I'm creating table and loading the data into it**

```
CREATE TABLE LogParserSample(

 month_name STRING, day STRING, time STRING, host STRING, event STRING, log STRING)

 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'   

 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (

  'input.regex' = '(^(\S+))\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+((\S+.)*)')

 stored as textfile;
```

**I'm using these websites to generate regex**

http://www.regexe.com/

http://rubular.com/

**These two are the regexes I'm using**

(\w{3})\s+(\w{1})\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+((\S+.)*)

(^(\S+))\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+((\S+.)*)

**Loading data and selecting**

```
load data local inpath '/home/programmeur_v/serde_dataset.txt' into table LogParserSample;

select * from LogParserSample;
```

**Output as null**

> hive> select * from LogParserSample;
>
> OK
>
> NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL    NULL
>
> NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
>
> NULL    NULL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
>
> NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
>
> NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
>
> NULL    NULL    NULL NULL    NULL    NULL
>
> NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
>
> Time taken: 0.094 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)

***Just new to the hive so don't know what exactly is the problem***

Comment: Can you try with `(\w{3})\s+(\w{1})\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)`

Comment: Hi Bala, i tried with this regex but this still loads null set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use **Java equivalent regex** while creating **Hive table using regex serde**.

> ***Try with below ddl:***

```
hive> CREATE TABLE LogParserSample(
 month_name STRING, day STRING, time STRING, host STRING, event STRING, log STRING)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'   
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'input.regex' = '(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.*)')
 stored as textfile;

hive> select * from LogParserSample;
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| month_name  | day  |   time    |   host    |        event         |                                                 log                                                 |
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| May         | 3    | 11:52:54  | cdh-dn03  | init:                | tty (/dev/tty6) main process (1208) killed by TERM signal                                           |
| May         | 3    | 11:53:31  | cdh-dn03  | kernel:              | registered taskstats version 1                                                                      |
| May         | 3    | 11:53:31  | cdh-dn03  | kernel:              | sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 32x/32x xa/form2 tray                                                         |
| May         | 3    | 11:53:31  | cdh-dn03  | kernel:              | piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr  |
| May         | 3    | 11:53:31  | cdh-dn03  | kernel:              | nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (7972 buckets, 31888 max)                                                |
| May         | 3    | 11:53:57  | cdh-dn03  | kernel:              | hrtimer: interrupt took 11250457 ns                                                                 |
| May         | 3    | 11:53:59  | cdh-dn03  | ntpd_initres[1705]:  | host name not found: 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org                                                            |
+-------------+------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Use [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) link to generate java equivalent regex.

Comment: @Vaibhav: Please accept the answer, if this has worked.